# Using a php script to overwrite index.html a few times a day

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, data-binding

Let's say I am creating a simple webpage where I write a sentence a couple times a day about my mood, each time overwriting the old sentence.

One way to do this could be to load the sentence from the database for every visitor, so the page load will look like this: html->javascript->php->mysql->php->javascript->html

However, I am concerned with performance, and I don't want to load the sentence from the database for every visitor because while it changes rarely, every visitor will invoke the repetitive data request which will add up and be a performance hit.

Since the content changes only a couple times a day, I was thinking to have a php script overwrite my index.html every time I want to replace my mood sentence with a new one, creating a brand new index.html with all the same content everywhere except the one changed div with the new mood.

I am wondering if this is an anti-pattern, and what I could do instead if I'm concerned with page load speed.

Comment: In this example, I have to use the database to store the old sentences, so just overwriting index.html manually is not an option.

Comment: Use a contab entry to hit a private php link that overwrites the page at whatever frequency you need. See if your webhost allows for crontab entries.

Comment: I am concerned with the general approach - is it bad design to overwrite and create a new index.html a few times a day?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too much here.  You'v said yourself that you rarely update this, and it's only 1 sentence long.  You can pretty much just EDIT the HTML file itself with your new sentence, and not use PHP at all.

I'm sorry I'm not answering your question, but I do believe you are approaching this in a manner that isn't necessary.

Comment: sorry, I was using an abstracted analogy, and this detail was lost. In my example, it would actually be other users who would write this sentence. They would upload a sentence to the database, and then the site will have to reflect the change somehow

Comment: so you will need to do an ajax call via javascript, retrieve the sentence from the database and insert it into a designated html container.  jquery has a $.post/$.get function which handles ajax calls nicely.  By doing this, you don't recreate the html file, you're just inserting the sentence into it upon every page request.